# Why can't I find the 'Function' function in webDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to implement a simple waitForXX under webdriver.

The code is pretty simple.

```
Function<WebDriver, WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator) {

    return new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {

            return driver.findElement(locator);

        }

    };
```

}

But still it gives me troubles because I can't seem to import the 'Function' part.

I looked every where under selenium.support.ui where it is supposed to be I guess? But I can't seem to locate it.

I tried with the latest Selenium standalone jar file 2.5.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<T>` that inherits from `Function<WebDriver, T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know how to do that in Java but have you had a look at the WebDriverWait class in WebDriver which should do what you want.

The class is in the Support part of the Java Bindings

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java

See how to use it with these tests

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWaitTest.java

Or you could use implicit waits

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, MILLISECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id('foo')); //will wait 3 seconds, if not loaded will throw an exception
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't want to wait Implicitly. That's never a good thing to do. BUT! The ExpectedCondition part is really appealing.

Answer (score 2):

[`Function<F, t>`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#UKMs0lhE9bg/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/Function.java&q=function%20package%3ahttp://guava-libraries%5C.googlecode%5C.com) seems to be from the [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Do you have the Guava jars?

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 since it was a good idea too! Thanks for your comment!